# (SSIS) Connection Manager Visual Studio 2015 that points to an XML file and schema?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2015

Can you create a connection in (SSIS) Connection Manager Visual Studio 2015 that points to an XML file and schema?[To appear with these other connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro1iX.png)